# Laravel 5.6 Passport oAuth2 can't make request with Guzzle

Tags: php, laravel, guzzle, laravel-5.6, laravel-passport

I have a fresh project on Laravel 5.6, where I'm trying to study and understand API Auth with Passport. I'm trying to do that, and after that to make a `Javascript` application from where I'll access that API. So, API for first-party applications.

I've installed and registered all routes and setup specific to passport, and also installed `Guzzle`.

I looked for some tutorials and now I'm with that code :

**RegisterController.php**

```
<?php
namespace App\Http\Controllers\Api\Auth;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;
use Laravel\Passport\Client;
use App\User;

class RegisterController extends Controller
{
    use IssueTokenTrait;

    private $client;

    public function __construct(){
        $this->client = Client::find(1); //Client 1 is a Laravel Password Grant Client token from my DB (when I wrote php artisan passport:install
    }

    public function register(Request $request){
        $this->validate($request, [
            'name' => 'required',
            'email' => 'required|email|unique:users,email',
            'password' => 'required|min:3',
            'password_confirmation' => 'required|same:password'
        ]);
        $user = User::create([
            'name' => request('name'),
            'email' => request('email'),
            'password' => bcrypt(request('password'))
        ]);
        return $this->issueToken($request, 'password');
    }

}
```

It uses `issueToken` function from that Trait :

**IssueTokenTrait.php**

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers\Api\Auth;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;
use GuzzleHttp\Client;

trait IssueTokenTrait{

    public function issueToken(Request $request, $grantType, $scope = ""){
        $params = [
            'grant_type' => $grantType,
            'client_id' => $this->client->id,
            'client_secret' => $this->client->secret,           
            'scope' => $scope
        ];

        $params['username'] = $request->username ?: $request->email;

        $request->request->add($params);
        $proxy = Request::create('oauth/token', 'POST');
        return Route::dispatch($proxy);
    }

}
```

**NOW THE PROBLEM : **
Everything works perfect. I can register, I have an access token which works on protected with `auth` routes, and doesn't work when I give a wrong token.
I read the documentation of `Passport` in `Laravel 5.6` and all examples use `GuzzleHttp` to make requests inside controller method, and I have tried to rewrite my code using `Guzzle` instead of `Request::dispatch`.

So, I found in multiple sources, in documentation as well code with different but also same logic implementation, so my **IssueTokenTrait** now looks like :

```
<?php 
namespace App\Http\Controllers\Api\Auth;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;
use GuzzleHttp\Client;

trait IssueTokenTrait{

    public function issueToken(Request $request, $grantType, $scope = ""){
        $params = [
            'grant_type' => $grantType,
            'client_id' => $this->client->id,
            'client_secret' => $this->client->secret,           
            'scope' => $scope
        ];

        $params['username'] = $request->username ?: $request->email;


        $url = url('/oauth/token');
        $headers = ['Accept' => 'application/json'];
        $http = new GuzzleHttp\Client;

        $response = $http->post($url, [
            'headers' => $headers,
            'form_params' => [
                'grant_type' => 'password',
                'client_id' => $this->client->id,
                'client_secret' => $this->client->secret,
                'username' => $request->email,
                'password' => $request->password
            ],
        ]);

        return json_decode((string)$response->getBody(), true);
    }

}
```

And there is how my app gets broken.
When I make a `POST` request to `/api/register` from `POSTMAN` now, it just not returns me a response, like `please wait...` and that's it. And if I restart my server, it returns me :
`[Mon Aug 20 11:29:16 2018] Failed to listen on 127.0.0.1:8000 (reason: Address already in use)`.
So, it looks like it makes this request, but it not returns the response, or it goes in a infinite loop.

I get stuck for a day with that problem, and really it looks like some mystic here. Because all parameters and values are like it was with `Route::dispatch`, just the method of making this `HTTP` request changes.

Comment: How are you starting your server? What OS are you on? Can you use valet? What are server logs saying, what about laravel logs?

Comment: Running on Linux Ubuntu 17.10.  I'm running server using `php artisan serve`. 
In Laravel logs, there are some entries like `class GuzzleHttp\Client` not found.` and when it's true, it returns me in `POSTMAN` same error. But when I change to a "right" use, it just breaks the server, and even in browser I can't run the `localhost:8000` server, cause it just running like in infinite loop, with no respose.

May be I `use` in the wrong way it in my `Trait`? ... I'm trying in all possible ways and it's still unsolved..

Comment: Did you `composer require` guzzle? Have you ran `composer dump-autoload` or `composer dump-autoload -o` if latter works you have typo in either class name or file name, fix it.

Comment: Nope, I ended up with a `Guzzle` problem described in one `GitHub` issue. It looks like when you write `php artisan serve` it's not the same like if you use some virtual servers. I asked for a friend to try it on `WAMPP` on windows and it works fine. So, problem seems to be in where you run your server, and/or because he uses `vhost`, but from `php artisan serve` I have to use `localhost:8000`.

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 options:

1. Try to run another Artisan server process with different port (ex: 8001) and guzzle to it.
2. Using personal access token instead, using `createToken` to generate access token.