# Guzzle post request to own server resulted in a `404 Not Found`

Tags: php, laravel, post, guzzle

I'm trying to sign into my laravel app which uses passport and added `guzzle` to post to my `oath/token` route so the user can sign in without me having to expose my `secret_key`

However I'm running into an error which I can't seem to solve

**Problem**

I've updated my laravel app with passport and tested my backend end locally which worked fine. After I deployed my laravel app to my live servers test environment I started to get errors while trying to sign in.

At first guzzle couldn't verify the SSL of my current live environment. So I turned verify to false. Now I've started to get a different which states my url `oath/token` route is wrong. Which is wrong because directly posting to my `oath/token' seems to work with postmen.

I've also checked if the route exists with `php artisan route:list`

*summarise: guzzle is stating the url I'm posting to doesn't exist, but it does*

**My get token function**

```
  public function getToken(& $username, $password)
  {
    $http = new \GuzzleHttp\Client;

    try {
      $response = $http->post(config('services.passport.login_endpoint'), [
          //'verify' => false,
          'verify'  => ( env( 'APP_ENV' ) === 'local' ) ? false : true,
          'form_params' => [
              'grant_type' => 'password',
              'client_id' => config('services.passport.client_id'),
              'client_secret' => config('services.passport.client_secret'),
              'scope' => '',
              'username' => $username,
              'password' => $password,
          ]
      ]);
      return $response->getBody();
    } catch (\GuzzleHttp\Exception\BadResponseException $e) {
        if ($e->getCode() === 400) {
            return response()->json('Invalid Request. Please enter a username or a password.', $e->getCode());
        } else if ($e->getCode() === 401) {
            return response()->json('Your credentials are incorrect. Please try again', $e->getCode());
        }
        return $e;
    }
  }
```

**Response**

```
GuzzleHttp\Exception\ClientException: Client error: `POST https: //my.domain.com/oauth/token` resulted in a `404 Not Found` response:
```

**Expectation**

Whenever `Guzzle` posts something to my existing route it returns response from my laravel app.

**ADDED DEBUG**

```
*   Trying {my ip adres}...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to {mydomain} {my ip adres} port 443 (#0)
* ALPN, offering http/1.1
* successfully set certificate verify locations:
*   CAfile: /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt
  CApath: /etc/ssl/certs
* SSL connection using TLSv1.2 / ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384
* ALPN, server accepted to use http/1.1
* Server certificate:
*  subject: C=CH; L=Schaffhausen; O=Plesk; CN=Plesk; emailAddress=info@plesk.com
*  start date: Feb  9 14: 54: 36 2020 GMT
*  expire date: Feb  8 14: 54: 36 2021 GMT
*  issuer: C=CH; L=Schaffhausen; O=Plesk; CN=Plesk; emailAddress=info@plesk.com
*  SSL certificate verify result: self signed certificate (18), continuing anyway.
> POST /oauth/token HTTP/1.1
Host: {mydomain}
User-Agent: GuzzleHttp/6.3.3 curl/7.58.0 PHP/7.1.33
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Content-Length: 144

* upload completely sent off: 144 out of 144 bytes
< HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
< Server: nginx
< Date: Wed,
01 Apr 2020 17: 31: 26 GMT
< Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1
< Content-Length: 266
< Connection: keep-alive
< 
* Connection #0 to host {mydomain} left intact
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
<html><head>
<title>404 Not Found</title>
</head><body>
<h1>Not Found</h1>
<p>The requested URL was not found on this server.</p>
<hr>
<address>Apache Server at my.domain.com Port 443</address>
</body></html>
```

**Routes**

```
|        | POST      | oauth/token                                 | passport.token          | Laravel\Passport\Http\Controllers\AccessTokenController@issueToken                                  | throttle                                                             |
|        | GET|HEAD  | oauth/tokens                                | passport.tokens.index   | Laravel\Passport\Http\Controllers\AuthorizedAccessTokenController@forUser                           | web,auth                                                             |
|        | DELETE    | oauth/tokens/{token_id}                     | passport.tokens.destroy | Laravel\Passport\Http\Controllers\AuthorizedAccessTokenController@destroy                           | web,auth                                                             |
```

Comment: why there is an extra space between `:` and `//` ?

Comment: @AlwaysSunny Don't know there is no space in the source. I've also tried to directly add the url

Comment: and how does the route you are trying to hit look with php artisan route:list?

Comment: @mrhn added it to the question

Comment: @Salman form the curl response it looks like your nginx webserver is already responding with a 404 page. Is nginx correclty configured to match your "hostname"? Are other routes working on the same hostname? Do you have custom `location` matches for this hostname configured?

Comment: @ChristophKluge Well calling to the same route (so the route that is online) from my local backend works. It also works with postman.

I haven't done any configuration with my ngix.

Comment: Have you tried caching routes via `php artisan route:cache` on the destination' server? Perhaps they have changed and you haven't updated them?

Comment: @DanielProtopopov I tried, but still the same response.

Comment: Double-check the URL used in Postman request and yours as a result in Guzzle. Below answer seems to have partially to do with it as you need full (sub-)domain path in Guzzle to make a request since it's not part of Laravel' test suite where you can do $this->post('/oauth/token'). That includes the port, protocol (HTTP/HTTPS) and leading slash (if any) at the end.

Comment: @DanielProtopopov I've checked the url. As I've said in my question, I've tried to directly add the url without importing it from the config and I still had the same response.

Comment: Then it looks like you will need to debug the incoming request and check what’s going on under. I sometimes encountered this, but debugging actually change the behavior once I stepped into vendor code. This might be related to PHP cache, too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the solution in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51927067/laravel-5-6-passport-oauth2-cant-make-request-with-guzzle) when I run `php artisan serve` I can call `'base_uri' => "127.0.0.1:8000"`. So I added it to [supervisor](http://supervisord.org/index.html) to run `php artisan serve` and I can now make a call to my own server.

Apparently I can't make a call to my own server over static PHP.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried to prepend your configured login.endpoint with the base url, so something like:

```
$response = $http->post(config('app.url'). config('services.passport.login_endpoint'), [
      ...
    ]
]);
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. I've tried directly putting the url there and I get the same errors